# SVG image pattern not visible in Firefox

Tags: html, image, firefox, svg

I have a simple inline SVG element which contains a rectangle filled with an image pattern. In IE11 and Chrome, the rectangle is displayed correctly every time. In Firefox however, the image is not visible on the first try but becomes visible when the page is loaded for the second time. According to my tests, Firefox displays the image only when it is cached. I see the problem in Firefox 51 and 52 on Windows; I haven't tested other versions or another OS.

To reproduce the problem in Firefox, you should clear the cache and restart the browser before running the code snippet:

Options | Advanced | Network | Cached Web Content | Clear Now

```html
<div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 240px; height: 180px;">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" x="0%" y="0%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="1" height="1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 4000 3000">
                <image xlink:href="http://www.public-domain-photos.com/free-stock-photos-3/landscapes/lakes/archipelago-4.jpg" width="4000" height="3000" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect fill="url('#pattern1')" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="1.0" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

In my current code, where SVG elements are added dynamically to the page, I workaround the problem by preloading the image before setting the image pattern. It works but I was wondering if there is a better solution to that problem. Many SVG elements can be added to the page, and each one can have a shape filled with an image pattern.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a pattern here.  Have you tried just using an `<image>` with a `<rect>` in front of it?   https://jsfiddle.net/8Lj899ud/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - The markup in my code snippet is simplified to show the problem. In my actual application, the SVG shape can be an ellipse or a path. The user can move, resize and rotate it; he can also move, resize and rotate the image inside of the shape. The image pattern seems to be the correct way to do it, and it works great. My current workaround allows me to use it even in Firefox but I don't see why I should have to do that. It looks like a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Ok. If you think you have found a bug in Firefox then you should [report it to them](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau - I just did it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1345853.

Comment: FYI xlink:href is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href